# What is the maximum size of data can be stored in kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

AWS Kinesis stream supports saving a record from 24 hours to 7 days of time. And it has a maximum one record size which is 1 megabyte but it doesn't say the maximum data can be saved in a kinesis stream. I wonder what if I put a large volume of data to a stream, will it run out of space?

Comment: Note, that an AWS Kinesis Stream can store data up to 365 days. Please check the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-extended-retention.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put as much data as you want which will require you to create more shards and as per below [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html). There is no upper limit on the number of shards you can have in a stream or account. However, shards will cost you money.

Data will be there depending upon your retention period and after that, it will be expired.